# err_cert_invalid at google chrome and opera

Tags: php, google-chrome, cpanel, opera

When I try to browse this site it always say connection is not private or certificate is unprotected:

[image]

Comment: By default the HOSTING providers use HTTPS in cPanel but without certificate, for this reason you need to buy one, also is possible that the certificate is not active

Comment: it Has certificate but still saying connection is not private @DavidAguilar

Comment: Have you checked the valid date for certificate? Had you got this error before?

Comment: yes, valid until next year and nope I never encounter this error before @DavidAguilar

Comment: as it says: **server's certificate does not match the URL** can't be much clearer

Comment: I tried to download certificate to fix this error, unfortunately it only increased the errors @Dagon

Comment: are you typing the URL as `https://aclcdau.com`, using HTTPS (443)?

Comment: "aclcdau.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. The certificate is only valid for jbcinnotech.com"

Comment: have you brought a certificate for "aclcdau.com"? you can't use the certificate for one site on another

Comment: Don't worry about it.  This happens in many shared hosting environments.  If you trust your hosting company, create the exception and enjoy cPanel.

Comment: yes i typed https://aclcdau.com @DavidAguilar

Comment: nope i didn't buy any certificate for aclcdau.com @Dagon

Comment: whenever I upload files or refresh the cpanel it always asking the password and username eventhough I laready login @user2182349

Comment: @DiannieSantos that certificate is not for your site, you are using a certificate for jbcinnotech.com, the information says: this certificate is issued by and for jbcinnotech.com, you need a valid certificate for aclcdau.com

Comment: Have you disabled cookies or are you using private / incognito browsing?

Comment: the certificate is cloud01.jollyworkshosting.com @DavidAguilar, so what should i do then?

Comment: no and I tried to use incognito still not working it always ask to login again @user2182349

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Google Chrome:

1. Put https://aclcdau.com:2083 in the address bar
2. You will see[image: something like this]
3. Click on Advanced in the lower left corner
4. Click on **Proceed to cloud01.jollyworkshosting.com**

Comment: it WORKS! I refresh, never ask me to login again, Thank you so much!

Comment: It gets easier ... good luck